# Invoking custom actions in a x64 assembly with a setup project

Tags: c#, .net, installation, windows-installer, 64-bit

I have a C# project targeted for x64 platforms. This project includes a `System.Configuration.Install.Installer` implementing some custom actions to be invoked by a setup project (a VS2010 MSI one).

When I run the installer in Win7 x64 it throws a `BadImageFormatException`. I guess this happens when the installer project is trying to load the x64 assembly containing the custom actions implementation.

I configured the setup project plataform as x64 but this problem makes me think the installer is still a 32bits executable.

Does anyone else came across with this kind of issue? Any sugestions to fix it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit old, but perhaps this will help: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/heaths/archive/2006/02/01/64-bit-managed-custom-actions-with-visual-studio.aspx